# Check if an email item in a shared mailbox is opened by another user

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

I am developing an Access (2016) multi-user application to access several shared mailboxes in order to move a batch of emails to a local folder for 'manual' processing by each user.

The procedure hangs on each email that is in 'open' state (opened by another user) and can only be interrupted using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. Very unpleasant.

How can I check that an email item is opened so the procedure can just skip it?

Comment: Have you checked the state of the MailItem.Conflicts property? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-conflicts-property-outlook)

Comment: Thanks Glorfindel, I found some code using that property:

...

 10 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 

 20 Dim myConflicts As Outlook.Conflicts 

 50 Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

 60 Set myConflicts = myItem.Conflicts 

 70 If myConflicts.Count > 0 Then MsgBox "This item is involved in a conflict."

...

but then, how to define '50 Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem' when Outlook is running on another user's pc and viewing a mailItem from a shared mailbox?

Comment: You may want to edit your question to add your code so that it is easier to read. Try using the [GetSharedDefaultFolder Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/namespace-getshareddefaultfolder-method-outlook)